# Dynamic run through a row of img tags (image slider)

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

First of all sorry for my bad English,

I'm trying to make a simple full-screen dynamic image slider with additional functions to be added later on. The idea is to display the next image tag every x seconds, and reaching the last tag, begin with the first again.

My only problem is that I can't find out how to display the next image tag in a row of tags WITHOUT naming it's class each time which wouldn't be too dynamic.

Example:

```
<div id="image_container">
    <img src="img/image1.jpg"/>
    <img src="img/image2.jpg"/>
    <img src="img/image3.jpg"/>
    <img src="img/image4.jpg"/>
</div>
```

For the css of the image tags I just set the display to none, and opacity to 0 to be able to fade the images in with an animation.

JS code I've used so far:

```
$(window).load(function(){

    $( "#image_container img" ).first().css( {"display":"block" } );
    $( "#image_container img" ).first().animate( {"opacity":"1" }, 2000 );
    $( "#image_container img" ).first().animate( {"opacity":"0" }, 2000 );

    $( "#image_container img" ).next().delay( 4000 );

    $( "#image_container img" ).next().css( {"display":"block" } );
    $( "#image_container img" ).next().animate( {"opacity":"1" }, 2000 );
    $( "#image_container img" ).next().animate( {"opacity":"0" }, 2000 );
});
```

This js code is obviously wrong and doesn't work properly at all...

Any help would be great since I'm only a first-year-student that doesn't has much experience with jquery.

Comment: Can you share the js code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/by8zz22s/1/

```
// Shortcut DOM ready handler
$(function(){
    // Avoid calling same selector multiple times - faster to reuse it
    var $image_container = $('#image_container');

    $image_container.children().first().addClass('active').fadeIn(2000);

    setInterval(function(){
        var $current = $image_container.children('.active');
        var $next = $current.next('img');
        if (!$next.length){
            $next = $image_container.children().first();
        }
        $current.removeClass('active').fadeOut(2000, function(){
            $next.fadeIn(2000).addClass('active');
        });
    }, 4000);

});
```

Notes:

- `$(function(){`is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function{` and is preferable to using `$(window).load(`
- It uses `setInterval` to generate a repeated event.
- It uses a class to identify the current image. This is added and removed dynamically.
- If there is no next image it simply wraps to the first image.
- I use $ prefixes for variables that contain jQuery objects (for readability)

**Update:**

This one allows for next and prev buttons, with varying delays: http://jsfiddle.net/by8zz22s/5/

```
$(function () {
    // Avoid calling same selector multiple times - faster to reuse it
    var $image_container = $('#image_container');

    $image_container.children().first().addClass('active').fadeIn(2000);

    // Function to show the next or previous image with transition    
    var updateDisplay = function (forward, delay) {

        clearInterval(timer);
        var $current = $image_container.children('.active');
        var $next = forward ? $current.next('img') : $current.prev('img');
        if (!$next.length) {
            $next = forward ? $image_container.children().first() : $image_container.children().last();
        }
        $current.removeClass('active').fadeOut(delay, function () {
            $next.fadeIn(delay).addClass('active');
        });
        // Start a new timout
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
            updateDisplay(forward, delay);
        }, 4000);
    };

    // Do initial interval with fade if delay of 2 seconds
    var timer = setTimeout(function () {
        updateDisplay(true, 2000);
    }, 4000);

    $('.button_next').click(function () {
        // Fast transition forwards
        updateDisplay(true, 200);
    });
    $('.button_previous').click(function () {
        // Fast transition backwards
        updateDisplay(false, 200);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes thanks TrueBlueAussie I think that will work for me, I will try to implement the code on my site and when it works mark your answer  as accepted :) Thanks again!

Comment: @Sander v. Hooff: I have aimed for readability over conciseness for you. You can place any animation inside the setInterval function. If you need info on how any of it works, just ask. :)

Comment: Just added an initial fade-in for first element, rather than wait 4 seconds :)

Comment: actually, Is there an easy way to add control arrows to go to the next or previous image, or even pauze the timer temporarily? (if I'm asking too much just say) thnx

Comment: @Sander v. Hooff: If you add the buttons and styling to my JSFiddle, I will add the code... It is pretty easy. :)

Comment: I made 2 buttons and gave them minimal styling: http://jsfiddle.net/by8zz22s/3/ (the styling and positioning of the buttons is not important right now, I'll do that later on ;)

Comment: @Sander v. Hooff: Should really have been a new question, but added example above. Enjoy :)